# Creating a bash alias to su to a new user and source a script

Tags: bash, su

I'd like to create a bash alias that does the following:

- `su` to another user
- `cd` to a certain directory
- `source` another script (specifically a python `virtualenv` activation script)

After running the alias, I would like to be logged in as the user, in the directory, with the virtualenv activated. I can get everything to work except for the `su`, which seems to live in its own parallel universe.

I can't see a way to make the `cd` and `source` run inside the `su` environment and stick, leaving me able to continue work inside the `su` environment. (e.g. `su -c` just runs the operations and leaves me where I started.)

**UPDATE:**

To clarify a bit, I want something like this:

```
sudo -u www-data bash -c 'cd /var/www; pwd; whoami'
```

But I want to remain in the interactive subshell until I `^D` out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about your `~/.bashrc`, you can just source your file instead of that:

```
su -c 'bash --rcfile myfile'
```

If you do care and your file only exports variables (i.e. doesn't define aliases or completion):

```
su -c 'source myfile; bash'
```

If you do need your `~/.bashrc` and you need defined aliases and completion, you can source both with:

```
su -s /bin/bash -c 'bash --rcfile <(echo "source ~/.bashrc; source myfile")'
```

Comment: My local bash guru came up with the same answer concurrently, but you beat him to the bunch. :) Thanks.